# como bloquear la tecla espacio en un campo de texto c#

Tags: c#

Cómo puedo bloquear la tecla espacio al escribir sobre un campo de texto para evitar que el usuario ingrese un espacio al registrar algo.
actualmente controlo solo letras y números en el `Keypress`.
necesito que no se envié ningún campo a la base de datos con espacios.

```
//letras y numeros
if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
{
   e.Handled = false;
}
else if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
     e.Handled = false;
}
else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
{
     e.Handled = false;
}
else if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
{
     e.Handled = false;
}
else
{
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: En principio el mecanismo es el mismo ¿cómo tienes el código y cual es el problema?

Comment: `char.IsWhiteSpace`

Comment: es que si el usuario digita su nombre e interpone un espacio se guarda de esa manera y no con su nombre correcto.

Comment: Como te comenta @sstan con `Char.IsWhiteSpace` puedes comprobar si el carácter es un espacio. Pero si no permites espacios en el campo nombre no se podrá introducir nombres compuestos

Comment: {
        if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
            MessageBox.Show("tecla espacio presionada");
    }

Comment: @sebastianbizamainostroza podrías evaluar usar este control personalizado para el manejo de letras, números, decimales. https://pedroavilanu.wordpress.com/2017/07/30/textbox-personalizado-textboxuniversal/   siempre y cuando estes trabajando con Windows forms

Comment: existe una funcion mas sencilla, no la recuerdo en estos momento, pero basicamnte hace que si un espacio no forma parte de la cade de string lo eliminina, por ejemplo textbox1[espacio codena1 cadena1 cadena3 espacio] aplicando la funcion solo retornaria [codena1 cadena1 cadena3] ya que el primer y ultimo espacio no forman parte de la cadena, solo los dos espacios que estan dentro de la cadena.

Answer (score 2):

Tu validación para separador tiene los e.handled al revez, debería de ser:

```
 if (char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
 {
     e.Handled = true;
 }
 else
 {
      e.Handled = false;
 }
```

por cierto, tenes que buscar el evento OnKeyPress